# Reprojecting vector layer of points QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector

I have a vector layer of 50 points with a CRS of OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84) and a raster layer with a CRS of EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. The vector layer of points doesn't line up correctly on the image, but when I reproject the vector layer so that its CRS matches that of the raster, the points don't move. I'm trying to get the set of green points to the pixel centroids. What can I do to shift my points to the correct position?

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

Comment: QGIS by default is doing on-the-fly projection on the background and therefore re-projecting the layer does not do anything visible because the transformations are the same. Show an example about your situation. Sample data would be appreciated.

Comment: @MrXsquared I tried to vectorize the raster, but got the error "ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db." How can I fix this?